# Do Mercenaries Get Replaced?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I hired Jenessa and I accidently killed her in a melee.

I know that there are a good few mercaneries in Skyrim, but as the question says,
Do the Mercenaries get replaced ? 
Or could I, in theory, hire and kill each one resulting in there being none left ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are a lot of mercenaries, but each is unique. Once Jenassa is killed, there won't be another Jenassa, or another mercenary to recruit in this tavern. And yes, you could theoretically hire and kill them all, and run out of mercenaries to hire.

Comment: @Terry If this answered your question, click the check mark to the left of the answer to let everyone know that this answer solved your problem.  Both you and the answerer will get rep, and future searchers won't have to look search through the comments!

Comment: @Dave McClelland Ahh thx. Didn't know about that yet. Have just done it :)